# Проблема с простым TCP сервером на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код с сервером:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

Код с клиентом:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.sendto('hello, world!', 'localhost', '9090')

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

Ошибка:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

В чём причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подключения вы использовали метод `socket.connect`, соответственно использовать после этого метод `socket.sendto` неправильно, так как метод `sendto` тоже устанавливает соединение.

А соединение у вас обрывается по той причине, что у вас сервер сейчас в случае закрытия соединения прекращает свою работу в строчке `if not data`. Таким образом последовательный вызов `connect` и `sendto` приводит к тому, что у вас в `sendto` закрывается текущее соединение и создается новое, а сервер к тому времени уже завершил работу.

Решение использовать метод `send` вместо `sendto`. И помните что при использовании метода `send` вы должны отправлять байты, а не строку.

Правильный клиент будет такой:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send(b'hello, world!')

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print(data)
```

Comment: sendall() иначе не всё может отослаться. recv() в явный цикл следует поместить или makefile(), чтобы удобней читать, иначе recv() не всё может вернуть.